# why do I sometimes get an Index error but sometimes not?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I got an index error but I can't figure out why.

```
import random

list1=[1,2]
list2=[[1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [2,1], [2,2]]

result = []

for i in list1:
    tmpList = []
    for j in list2:
        if j[0] == i:
            tmpList.append(j)
    if len(tmpList)> 0:
        k = random.randint(0, len(tmpList))
        result.append(tmpList[k])

print(result)
```

This code could sometimes give me a result, but sometimes give me

```
"IndexError: list index out of range" on 
---> 15         result.append(tmpList[k])
```

Comment: Try `len(tmpList) - 1`

Answer (score 1):

The random function generates a number between the first and last number both included. So it can also be the len(tmpList). As there are only len(list)-1 indexes in any list if the random function generates the highest possible value the index is out of range. So in this specific case you will get an error.

To solve that use:

```
import random

list1=[1,2]
list2=[[1,2], [1,3], [1,4], [2,1], [2,2]]

result = []

for i in list1:
    tmpList = []
    for j in list2:
        if j[0] == i:
            tmpList.append(j)
    if len(tmpList)> 0:
        k = random.randint(0, len(tmpList)-1)
        result.append(tmpList[k])

print(result)
```

Comment: And what is the solution?

Comment: @Selcuk using randint properly ;) (a.k.a not going out of bounds)

Answer (score 1):

The python `random.randint( a, b )` [function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) returns a number a <= N <= b

So sometimes this is returning a `k` which equals `len(tmpList)`, and `tmpList` can only be indexed `0` -> `len(tmpList)-1`

Try:

```
k = random.randint(0, len(tmpList)-1)
result.append(tmpList[k])
```